# How to set free trials with firebase stripe extension

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I am wondering if it is currently possible to create free trials with the firebase stripe extension...

```
 const sessionRef = await addDoc(
        collection(db, "users", user.uid, "checkout_sessions"),
        {
          price: selectedProduct.priceId, // Use the price ID from the selected product
          success_url: `${window.location.origin}/selector/dashboard`,
          cancel_url: `${window.location.origin}/upgrade`,
          allow_promotion_codes: true,
          trial_period_days: 7, // Added the trial period here
          trial_from_plan: true, // added true
        },
      );
```

I read somewhere you could add the trial period and trial_from_plan - but I'm not finding the ability to actually set a trial period anywhere when I create a product on the stripe site.

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: The extension does not support this at the moment unfortunately. You can see https://github.com/invertase/stripe-firebase-extensions/issues/541 which was closed as "not planned" so it'd be a feature request you can ask them for

Comment: I managed to get it to work with a legacy model but i had to create the product through the billing page - kind of a bug in their system

Answer (score 0):

Thomas's answer worked for me:

I managed to get it to work with a legacy model but i had to create the product through the billing page - kind of a bug in their system –
Thomas Ventura
yesterday